# FFMPEG: Video file to YUV conversion by binary ffmpeg and by code C++ give different results

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, yuv

***Disclaimer:*** I have looked at the following question, 
[FFMPEG: RGB to YUV conversion by binary ffmpeg and by code C++ give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449177/ffmpeg-rgb-to-yuv-conversion-by-binary-ffmpeg-and-by-code-c-give-different-re)
but it didn't help and it is not applicable to me because I am not using SwsContext or anything.

Following first few tutorials by http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/, I have created a simple program that reads a video, decodes it and then when the frame is decoded, it writes the raw yuv values to a file (no padding), using the data provided by AVFrame after we successfully decoded a frame. To be more specific, I write out arrays `AVFrame->data[0]`, `AVFrame->data[1]` and `AVFrame->data[2]` to a file, i.e. I simply append Y values, then U values, then V values to a file. The file turns out to be of yuv422p format.

When I convert the same original video to a raw yuv format using the ffmpeg(same version of ffmpeg) command line tool, the two yuv files are the same in size, but differ in content.

FYI, I am able to play both of the yuv files using the yuv player, and they look identical as well.

Here is the exact command I run to convert the original video to a yuv video using ffmpeg command line tool

```
 ~/bin/ffmpeg -i super-short-video.h264 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p  "super-short-video-yuv422p.yuv"
```

What causes this difference in bytes and can it be fixed? Is there perhaps another way of converting the original video to a yuv using the ffmpeg tool but maybe I need to use different settings?

Ffmpeg output when I convert to a yuv format:

```
ffmpeg version N-80002-g5afecff Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/me/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/me/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/me/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/me/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-pg --extra-ldflags=-pg --disable-stripping
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 42.100 / 57. 42.100
  libavformat    57. 36.100 / 57. 36.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 45.100 /  6. 45.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, h264, from 'super-short-video.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn
[rawvideo @ 0x24f6fc0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'super-short-video-yuv422p.yuv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (Y42B / 0x42323459), yuv422p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.42.100 rawvideo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   50 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=   90000kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=368640.0kbits/s speed=11.3x    
video:90000kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

Comment: Your input and output (according to `ffmpeg` output) is yuv420p. What makes you say it's yuv422p? Also, your command line and `ffmpeg`'s output don't match. The command line says you're outputting yuv422p, but `ffmpeg`'s output says it's yuv420p.

Comment: I apologize, I have run the command again and pasted the latest output and the exact command I used.

Comment: I am still having the same problem. The two yuv files are different :(

Comment: Thanks for adding the correct command and output. Unfortunately, you're question still doesn't include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's impossible to tell you what you're doing wrong without seeing the code you're using to write the video file from `AVFrame`.